# Volume of tetrahedron (integral). What function do I have to integrate?

Tags: integration, volume, simplex

Let $A = \left \{ (x,y,z)\in [0, 1]^{3}| x + y + z \leq 1 \right \}$. Calculate the volume.

So I found the following boundaries for the integrals:

- $0 \leq z\leq 1$
- $0 \leq y\leq 1-z$
- $0 \leq x\leq 1-y-z$

The integral is $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-z}\int_{0}^{1-y-z}f(x,y,z)dx dy dz$. But what is f(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are integrating $f(x, y, z) =1$.

Comment: Why? Is this always the case, if there is no f(x,y,z) given?

Comment: I think I understand it. Integrating 1 is just giving the volume of the domain we want to integrate. For example if I want to know the volume/length of an real interval [a, b] I can integrate f(x) = 1 with respect to the boundaries a and b.

Comment: @Aurelius Yes that's right.